# awk + doing a group summation using awk with for loop for reading in and outputting

Tags: bash, awk

this is my file:

```
$ cat -v  head_datafile_pipe_deleimiter_more_columns.csv
"Rec_Open_Date"|"MSISDN"|"IMEI"|"Data_Volume_Bytes"|"Device_Manufacturer"|"Device_Model"|"Product_Description"|"Data_Volume_MB"|">20MB/30"|">200MB/30"|">2048MB/30"|">5120MB/30"|">10240MB/30"
"2016-07-25"|"537"|"190"|"48195367"|"Samsung Korea"|"Samsung SM-G928I"|"$49.95 Carryover Plan"|"45.9627"|"1"|"1"|"0"|"0"|"0"
"2016-07-25"|"370"|"780"|"92875513"|"Samsung Korea"|"Samsung SM-J500Y"|"$39.95 Plan"|"88.573"|"1"|"1"|"1"|"0"|"0"
"2016-07-25"|"024"|"640"|"35174867"|"Samsung Korea"|"Samsung GT-I9505"|"$29.95 Plan"|"33.5454"|"1"|"1"|"0"|"0"|"0"
"2016-07-25"|"091"|"660"|"0"|"LG Electronics Inc."|"LG LG-D802"|"PREPAY  PLUS - TRIAL - #16"|"0"|"0"|"0"|"0"|"0"|"0"
"2016-07-25"|"706"|"300"|"33352130"|"Apple Inc"|"Apple iPhone 5S A1530"|"PREPAY PLUS - $0 -"|"31.8071"|"1"|"1"|"0"|"0"|"0"
"2016-07-25"|"917"|"350"|"85820068"|"Apple Inc"|"Apple iPhone 6S Plus A1687"|"$39.95 Plan"|"81.8444"|"1"|"1"|"1"|"0"|"0"
"2016-07-25"|"027"|"070"|"9718436"|"Samsung Korea"|"Samsung SM-G900F"|"$29.95 Plan"|"9.26822"|"1"|"1"|"0"|"0"|"0"
"2016-07-25"|"173"|"780"|"19152160"|"Apple Inc"|"Apple iPhone 6S A1688"|"$49.95 Plan"|"18.2649"|"1"|"1"|"0"|"0"|"0"
"2016-07-25"|"685"|"140"|"17443425"|"Apple Inc"|"Apple iPhone 6S Plus A1687"|"$89.95 Plan"|"16.6353"|"1"|"1"|"0"|"0"|"0"
```

this is the array I create

```
$ mapfile -t u_vals <<<"$(awk -F'|' 'NR>1{print $7}' head_datafile_pipe_deleimiter_more_columns.csv | sort | uniq)"
$ declare -p u_vals
declare -a u_vals='([0]="\"\$29.95 Plan\"" [1]="\"\$39.95 Plan\"" [2]="\"\$49.95 Carryover Plan\"" [3]="\"\$49.95 Plan\"" [4]="\"\$89.95 Plan\"" [5]="\"PREPAY  PLUS - TRIAL - #16\"" [6]="\"PREPAY PLUS - \$0 -\"")'
```

THis is an example of the output I want, but this only sums columns 8-9, I want to do columns 8-NF. And this does not use a for loop.

```
$ for el in "${u_vals[@]}"; do  awk -F"|" -v q='"' -v j="$el" '
NR>1{if($7 == j) {gsub(/"/,"",$8); sum+=$8; gsub(/"/,"",$9); sum2+=$9} }; NR>1{count++} END { print "output" FS j FS q count q FS sum FS sum2}' head_datafile_pipe_deleimiter_more_columns.csv; done | cat -n
     1  output|"$29.95 Plan"|"9"|42.8136|2
     2  output|"$39.95 Plan"|"9"|170.417|2
     3  output|"$49.95 Carryover Plan"|"9"|45.9627|1
     4  output|"$49.95 Plan"|"9"|18.2649|1
     5  output|"$89.95 Plan"|"9"|16.6353|1
     6  output|"PREPAY  PLUS - TRIAL - #16"|"9"|0|0
     7  output|"PREPAY PLUS - $0 -"|"9"|31.8071|1
```

But I want to create a for loop for cols 8-NF, which I am trying to do here for col 8-9 `{for(i=8;i<=9;i++) gsub(/"/,"",$i); sum[i]+=$i}`, but I am not sure if it can be done

```
$ for el in "${u_vals[@]}"; do  awk -F"|" -v q='"' -v j="$el" '
NR>1{if($7 == j) {for(i=8;i<=9;i++) gsub(/"/,"",$i); sum[i]+=$i} }; NR>1{count++} END { for(i=8;i<=9;i++) print "output" FS j FS q count q FS sum[i] FS sum[i]}' head_datafile_pipe_deleimiter_more_columns.csv; done | cat -n
```

This is my desired output, this just has cols 8 and 9 grouping summed here:

```
........................|col8   |col9|...

output|"$29.95 Plan"|"9"|42.8136|2|<other column sums here>
output|"$39.95 Plan"|"9"|170.417|2 ...
output|"$49.95 Carryover Plan"|"9"|45.9627|1
output|"$49.95 Plan"|"9"|18.2649|1
output|"$89.95 Plan"|"9"|16.6353|1
output|"PREPAY  PLUS - TRIAL - #16"|"9"|0|0
output|"PREPAY PLUS - $0 -"|"9"|31.8071|1|<other column sums here>
```

---

### EDIT1

trying to understand the difference between `print` `printf` this is me playing which helps.

the only difference between the 2 below commands:

`print ("output" FS j FS q count q FS sum[8]);`

`printf ("output" FS j FS q count q FS sum[8]);`

```
$ for el in "${u_vals[@]}"; do  awk -F"|" -v q='"' -v j="$el" '
NR>1{if($7 == j) {for(i=8;i<=NF;i++){gsub(/"/,"",$i); sum[i]+=$i}} }; NR>1{count++} END { print ("output" FS j FS q count q FS sum[8]); for(i=8;i<=NF; i++){ printf("%s",FS sum[i])} printf("\n")}' head_datafile_pipe_deleimiter_more_columns.csv; done | cat -n
     1  output|"$29.95 Plan"|"9"|42.8136
     2  |42.8136|2|2|0|0|0
     3  output|"$39.95 Plan"|"9"|170.417
     4  |170.417|2|2|2|0|0
     5  output|"$49.95 Carryover Plan"|"9"|45.9627
     6  |45.9627|1|1|0|0|0
     7  output|"$49.95 Plan"|"9"|18.2649
     8  |18.2649|1|1|0|0|0
     9  output|"$89.95 Plan"|"9"|16.6353
    10  |16.6353|1|1|0|0|0
    11  output|"PREPAY  PLUS - TRIAL - #16"|"9"|0
    12  |0|0|0|0|0|0
    13  output|"PREPAY PLUS - $0 -"|"9"|31.8071
    14  |31.8071|1|1|0|0|0
1415137039 [main] -sh 4624 sig_send: error sending signal -66, pipe handle 0x1210, nb 132, packsize 0, Win32 error 0

$ for el in "${u_vals[@]}"; do  awk -F"|" -v q='"' -v j="$el" '
NR>1{if($7 == j) {for(i=8;i<=NF;i++){gsub(/"/,"",$i); sum[i]+=$i}} }; NR>1{count++} END { printf ("output" FS j FS q count q FS sum[8]); for(i=8;i<=NF; i++){ printf("%s",FS sum[i])} printf("\n")}' head_datafile_pipe_deleimiter_more_columns.csv; done | cat -n
     1  output|"$29.95 Plan"|"9"|42.8136|42.8136|2|2|0|0|0
     2  output|"$39.95 Plan"|"9"|170.417|170.417|2|2|2|0|0
     3  output|"$49.95 Carryover Plan"|"9"|45.9627|45.9627|1|1|0|0|0
     4  output|"$49.95 Plan"|"9"|18.2649|18.2649|1|1|0|0|0
     5  output|"$89.95 Plan"|"9"|16.6353|16.6353|1|1|0|0|0
     6  output|"PREPAY  PLUS - TRIAL - #16"|"9"|0|0|0|0|0|0|0
     7  output|"PREPAY PLUS - $0 -"|"9"|31.8071|31.8071|1|1|0|0|0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply iterate over 8 to NF. You also must replace the final `print` call in the `END` block with one initial `printf` to print the fields that you want to output prior to the 8:NF fields, then use a `printf` call inside the for-loop to print the 8:NF fields, and finally print a newline after the for-loop. We must use `printf` instead of `print` for the former two prints to prevent the newline from being printed prematurely.

```
for el in "${u_vals[@]}"; do

    awk -F\| -v q=\" -v j="$el" '

        NR > 1 {
            if ($7 == j) {
                for (i = 8; i <= NF; ++i) {
                    gsub(/"/,"",$i);
                    sum[i] += $i;
                }
            }
            ++count;
        };

        END {
            printf("%s","output" FS j FS q count q);
            for (i = 8; i <= NF; ++i)
                printf("%s",FS sum[i]);
            printf("\n");
        };

    ' head_datafile_pipe_deleimiter_more_columns.csv;

done| cat -n;
##      1  output|"$29.95 Plan"|"9"|42.8136|2|2|0|0|0
##      2  output|"$39.95 Plan"|"9"|170.417|2|2|2|0|0
##      3  output|"$49.95 Carryover Plan"|"9"|45.9627|1|1|0|0|0
##      4  output|"$49.95 Plan"|"9"|18.2649|1|1|0|0|0
##      5  output|"$89.95 Plan"|"9"|16.6353|1|1|0|0|0
##      6  output|"PREPAY  PLUS - TRIAL - #16"|"9"|0|0|0|0|0|0
##      7  output|"PREPAY PLUS - $0 -"|"9"|31.8071|1|1|0|0|0
```

Comment: tks. note you use `-F\| -v q=\" v. `-F"|" -v q='"'`  and also `++i` v. `i++`